# Screenshot+upload software for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I'm looking for a screenshot and upload tool similar to Gyazo and ShareX, that allows me to take screenshots of a certain area, or a whole window, etc and then gives me a link that it was uploaded to after.

Does anyone know of any decent software for this on Ubuntu 18?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by *a link that it was uploaded* ?

Comment: @Bruni I don't think this is a duplicate. None of the answers there support uploading.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**flameshot**](https://github.com/lupoDharkael/flameshot). It uploads images to [imgur](https://imgur.com/) and returns the URL.

Flameshot is a powerful open source screenshot and annotation tool for Linux. It has a varied set of editing tools available, including:

- Freehand drawing
- Lines
- Arrows
- Boxes
- Circles
- Highlighting
- Blur

You can customise the color, size and/or thickness of many of these image annotation tools. It is directly available in 18.04 from the universe/graphics repository.